# Can a Pakistani visit Dubai without visa if I have a valid US Green Card?

Tags: visas, dubai, flydubai

I am a US Green Card holder and a Pakistani origin.

My question is that can I visit Dubai without acquiring a visa?

PS: I have been in Pakistan for more than a year

Comment: All the information you need can be found on this page: https://u.ae/en/information-and-services/visa-and-emirates-id/do-you-need-an-entry-permit-or-a-visa-to-enter-the-uae

Comment: Along with a short quote of the elements relevant to OP’s situation, this would be an answer.

Comment: If you have been outside the US for more than a year you are no longer a green card holder.

Comment: @JonCuster that is incorrect.  The green card is not valid for entry into the US, but it is valid for every other purpose until its expiration date or until permanent residence status is lost, which can only happen if the permanent resident formally relinquishes it or if there is a formal finding of abandonment of permanent residence.

Comment: @ThomasCruise that link specifically tells that you can travel to Dubai if you are GC holder and Indian origin, not sure about Pakistanis